# Web page refreshes between http GET method, calculating parameters and POST method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have a page to parse (scrape) but firstly I have to pass control measures.
There are some control numbers I manage to calculate, and when I try to pass these control numbers and other stuff via POST method parameters, I think page refresh itself and generate new control numbers so those I calculated don't pass check and I fail to access desired page.

At first, I get the page with HtmlAgilityPack methods and get values of these control numbers:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument mainPage = web.Load(url);
int controlNumber = FindControlNumber();
```

Straight after that I try to pass calculated number via POST method:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string data = @"id=" + id + "&controlNumber=" + controlNumber;
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

But then instead of navigating to desired page, the initial page is shown with message "Wrong control number".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of controlNumber?

Comment: Control number is 3 digit integer. I'm sure it's correctly calculated. What worries me, is that maybe connection or session expires, or something like that, what forces page reloading and generating new controls numbers, which makes calculated control number value old.

Comment: Are you sure the control number you are passing is really valid? And if it's scraping, are you sure there aren't any cookies or any other important headers that you are missing? Or maybe additional POST parameters? This is what I'd be looking at, your code seems fine for getting the page's content.

Comment: Here are results from FireBug:

Response Headers

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 12463
Via: 1.1 ISA
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2013 08:46:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1250
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=9999
Content-Language: hr-HR

Comment: Request Headers

POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: fullpath
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000JYccePLaGcExgXWT9pMNtfJ:13fshcske
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Scraping is acting like a web browser user would act. It includes entering through the main page, logging in if necessary and navigating through menus to get to the desired page. On any of those steps you might be getting some cookies or tokens that you might have to include in your later requests. Or maybe there's some kind of authorization process - who knows? There are many, many possibilities and posting only the last request/response pair really doesn't help much. You need to repeat all steps a web browser user would make. It's really a broader issue.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the only thing I had to to was set up cookies and use WebRequest and WebResponse instead of HPA's HtmlWeb.
Here's code that works:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer(); // instantiate cookie container

        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Calculate control number...

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string data = @"id=" + id + "&controlNumber=" + controlNumber;
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;

        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```